# DAX: How to check if (All) value selected for specific Dimension

Tags: multidimensional-array, ssas, mdx, dax, tabular

I have a task to convert existing MDX measures (from multidimensional model) into DAX (tabular model).
There is a part of code which I'm doing right now:

`IIF(
 [Product].[Status].Level IS [Product].[Status].[(All)]
AND 
[Product].[Brand].Level IS [Product].[Brand].[(All)]
AND 
[Product].[Category].Level IS [Product].[Category].[(All)]
,[Measures].[Full_Amount]
,NULL
)`

[image]

How can I do the same on DAX?
The problem is to check that .[(All)] member is selected. Do we have the same option n DAX?

Comment: Check DAX functions ISFILTERED and ISCROSSFILTERED. Absense of filters is equivalent to ALL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @RADO mentions you can do something like this in `DAX`:

```
IF(
   NOT ISFILTERED( Product[Status] )
   && NOT ISFILTERED( Product[Brand] )
   && NOT ISFILTERED( Product[Category] ),
  [Measures].[Full_Amount],
  BLANK()
)
```